# Fazer um INSERT com restrição de integridade

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou com duas tabelas:

Tabela pessoa:

```
CREATE TABLE T_AM_OME_PESSOA
(
cd_pessoa NUMBER (8) NOT NULL ,
nm_pessoa VARCHAR2 (60) NOT NULL
) ;
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_PESSOA ADD CONSTRAINT PK_AM_PESSOA PRIMARY KEY ( cd_pessoa ) ;
```

e tabela forum:

```
CREATE TABLE T_AM_OME_FORUM
(
cd_forum NUMBER (8) NOT NULL ,
ds_forum VARCHAR2 (256) NOT NULL
) ;
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_FORUM ADD CONSTRAINT PK_AM_FORUM PRIMARY KEY ( cd_forum ) ;
```

e os relacionamentos

```
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_FORUM ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AM_PESSOA_FORUM FOREIGN KEY ( cd_forum ) REFERENCES T_AM_OME_PESSOA ( cd_pessoa ) ;
```

e sequencia

```
-- Sequencia tabela T_AM_OME_PESSOA
CREATE SEQUENCE SQ_AM_OME_PESSOA
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
MAXVALUE 99999999
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;
```

sendo que na implementação pessoa será uma classe abstrata..
atualmente via banco, para cadastrar um forum, eu primeiro cadastro um nome qualquer na tabela PESSOA e uso o valor gerado da sequencia como chave primaria para cd_forum. porem, gostaria de cadastrar forum diretamente, efetuando registro tanto na tabela pessoa quanto na tabela forum simultaneamente.

Meu DAO

```
public void gravar(Forum f, Connection conexao) throws Exception {

    String sql1 = "insert into T_AM_OME_PESSOA" + "(CD_PESSOA, NM_PESSOA) values (SQ_AM_OME_PESSOA.NEXTVAL,?)";
    PreparedStatement estrutura = conexao.prepareStatement(sql1);
    estrutura.setString(1, f.getNm_pessoa());
    estrutura.execute();
    estrutura.close();

    String sql2 =  "insert into T_AM_OME_FORUM" + "(CD_FORUM, DS_FORUM) values(?,?)";
    PreparedStatement estrutura2 = conexao.prepareStatement(sql2);
    estrutura2.setInt(1, f.getCd_pessoa());
    estrutura2.setString(2, f.getDs_forum());
    estrutura2.execute();
    estrutura2.close();
```

classe de teste

```
f.setNm_pessoa(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome do forum "));
        f.setCd_forum(f.getCd_pessoa());
        f.setDs_forum(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Descricao do forum "));
        ForumBo.grava(f,con);
```

esta dando

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291:
>   restrição de    integridade (SYSTEM.FK_AM_PESSOA_FORUM) violada -
>   chave mãe não localizada

alguma sugestao para esse INSERT simultaneo em PESSOA E FORUM? obs.: a classe Forum extends Pessoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mariana,

Acho que você pode tentar fazer a recuperação da sequence antes de executar os inserts. Algo assim:

```
// Objeto que manterá o valor das duas PKs
BigDecimal nextVal = BigDecimal.ZERO;

// Consulta sequence para obter próximo valor
String sql0 = "select SQ_AM_OME_PESSOA.NEXTVAL from DUAL";
PreparedStatement estrutura = conexao.prepareStatement(sql0);
ResultSet rs = estrutura.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
   BigDecimal nextVal = rs.getBigDecimal(1);
}
estrutura.close();

// Insere pessoa
String sql1 = "insert into T_AM_OME_PESSOA" + "(CD_PESSOA, NM_PESSOA) values (?,?)";
PreparedStatement estrutura = conexao.prepareStatement(sql1);
estrutura.setBigDecimal(1, nextVal); // Seta o valor obtido na consulta a sequence
estrutura.setString(2, f.getNm_pessoa());
estrutura.execute();
estrutura.close();

// Realiza o commit para garantir que os dados de pessoa foram inseridos
conexao.commit();

// Insere o forum
String sql2 =  "insert into T_AM_OME_FORUM" + "(CD_FORUM, DS_FORUM) values(?,?)";
PreparedStatement estrutura2 = conexao.prepareStatement(sql2);
estrutura2.setInt(1, nextVal);// Seta o valor obtido na consulta a sequence
estrutura2.setString(2, f.getDs_forum());
estrutura2.execute();
estrutura2.close();
```

Tente compilar o código acima e, se funcionar, nos dê seu feedback, ok?

Abs

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente. Obrigada!

Comment: Por nada... Disponha!!!

Comment: Mariana, Só uma dúvida: sua modelagem está incluindo uma FK entre duas PKs... isso é "bastante incomum"... Você tem mesmo a necessidade de ter duas tabelas com o mesmo valor sendo PK???

Comment: acredito que para essa tabela realmente não seja relevante ter o mesmo valor para PK. Eu utilizei recentemente 2 tabelas que possuíam uma relacionamento m:n (muitos-para-muitos) e na normalização, não utilizei entidade associativa porém utilizei o mesmo valor que era PK em uma tabela como FK em outra tabela para formar uma chave primaria composta e foi muito importante para garantir unicidade de dados

Comment: Outra ideia também para a questão proposta (depois eu pensei em outras alternativas), foi fazer o resgate desse valor via banco através de uma subconsulta. Funcionou.